# java http request cannot post

Tags: java, node.js, express, webserver

I have a nodejs web server running and I want to a body to the request in my java program.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .GET()
            .header( "Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
            .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:3000"))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Hello"))
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    System.out.println("status:" + response.statusCode());
    System.out.println("response:" + response.body());
```

If I delete this line: `.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Hello"))` everything works fine, I get the response from the server, but there is no body to the request.
With this line I get status code 404 and the body of the response to the client is:
[image]

How can I add body to the request?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try understand differences between GET and POST HTTP methods
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

There is also a good example in docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html

```
 HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://example.com/"))
            .header("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("some body text"))
            .build();
```

You can also look here as well
https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client

Comment: Thank you for the sources, definitely halped me to understand a little bit more. But I still have the same issue.